# Reading XML from REST API

Tags: c#, xml, rest

I am writing a small console application in C# to send a request to REST API and receive the response in XML. below is my code

```
 using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(reader.ReadToEnd());
                Console.Write(xmlDoc);

            }
```

I have checked using the fiddler and i am getting 200 response code and result. but while doing  `xmlDoc.Load(reader.ReadToEnd());` i am getting error.

Can any one help me to solve this? or is there any other way to do this.

**I want to write the response XML result into file.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Any clue as to waht error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        string response;
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader((webRequest.GetResponse()).GetResponseStream()))
            {
                response = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
                streamIn.Close();
            }
        }finally
        {webRequest.Abort();}

       XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(response);
```